# Confusion about two pair rule in poker, can someone help me who will win

Tags: poker-theory, pocket-pair

[image]

Hello guys please help here. i think it is a draw what do you say?

Comment: Yes, it's a split pot. The best 5-card hand for each player is QQJJ8. Poker hands have *exactly five cards*, no more, no fewer, and Texas Hold'em hands are the best five cards out of the seven available.

Comment: got it! thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A poker hand is built with 5 cards (and no more than 5). There is no limit to how many of those cards come from your hole cards, and how many of those come from the table (community cards)

For instance, if the board comes 23456, and your hole cards are A9, you will build your hand using all 5 community cards, getting a straight.

In the situation your present, both players would get a QQJJ8 as their hand (the pair of 3's is irrelevant since any 5-card combination cointaining threes would be worse than QQJJ8). The pot is therefore split